# How to make a WPF ScrollViewer use only the available width?

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf window, and there is a footer sections that can have multiple content which makes the width of the footer grows.

I set SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" in my Window and when I add a lot of content to ScrollViewer, it grows accordingly, instead of just show the scrollbar.

It looks like ScrollViewer is taking into account its content, so how do I set the ScrollViewer to ignore it's content and only take the width available instead of make it grow?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that by setting `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` you tell the controls inside the window that they "can have all the space they want", so the ScrollViewer does not do anything becase it is not being restricted by its parent which is a necessary condition for a ScrollViewer to work (and make sense).

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the MaxWidth property of the ScrollViewer. Once it has reached this width, it should start showing scrollbars.